# Use key of groupby to create another column pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

**df**

```
order_date    month      year   Days  Data
2015-12-20     12        2014    1     3
2016-1-21      1         2014    2     3
2015-08-20     8         2015    1     1 
2016-04-12     4         2016    4     1

and so on
```

**Code:**(finding mean, min, and median of days column and finding number of order_dates month wise for each respective year)

```
df1 = (df.groupby(["year", "month"])
     .agg(Min_days=("days", 'min'),
          Avg_days=("days", 'mean'),
          Median_days=('days','median'),
          Count = ('order_date', 'count'))
     .reset_index())
```

df1

```
   year  month  Min_days    Avg_days    Median_days     Count
    2015   1       9        12.56666666          10         4
    2015   2       10       13.67678788          9          3    
   ........................................................
    2016   12       12       15.7889990           19          2
    and so on...
```

**Issue at hand:**

I **want to have another column month name in the table using key month from df1**. Im doing this:

Output I want:

```
    year month Min_days       Avg_days    Median_days     Count    Month Name
    2015   1       9        12.56666666          10         4       Jan
    2015   2       10       13.67678788          9          3       Feb
   ........................................................
    2016   12       12       15.7889990         19          2     Dec
    and so on...

import calendar
df1['Month Name']=df1['month'].apply(lambda x:calendar.month_abbr[x])
```

But I am getting keyword error: month. I am unable to use key month to create another column month name. Pls help

Comment: What is `print (df.index.names)
print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: How about you do the 'df1['Month Name']=df1['month'].apply(lambda x:calendar.month_abbr[x])' before the groupby. If that is not possible, you can consider doin a join instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no column `month`, resaon should be `month` is `level` of `MultiIndex`.

Check it :

```
print (df1.index.names)
print (df1.columns.tolist())
```

So need:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df1['Month Name']=df1['month'].apply(lambda x:calendar.month_abbr[x])
```

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor - Sorry, I think `df1` like `print (df1.index.names)
print (df1.columns.tolist())`

Comment: df1.index.names is giving me output ['year', 'month']

Comment: 2nd df1.columns.tolist() output is  ['Min_days', 'Avg_days', 'Median_days', 'Count']

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor - It seems `.reset_index()` is missing here

Answer (score 1):

You can try map with `get_level_values` for multiindex mapping:

```
s = df1.index.get_level_values(1).map({i:e for i,e in enumerate([*calendar.month_abbr])})
df1 = df1.assign(Month=pd.Series(s,index=df1.index)
```

Or even simpler without apply ,if the dataframe is not a multi index and already reset, just use

```
df1 = df1.assign(Month=np.array(calendar.month_abbr)[df1['month']])
```